# Is it possible to jump to an Outlook calendar invite directly from a cancelled email notification

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Within Outlook (in the browser), if some one declines a meeting I often have to reschedule.

When they decline, I see something like this

[image]

When receiving emails like this, my action is to open the calendar invite and enter a new time but my first challenge is locating the invite in my calendar. I'd like to make this easier.

If you look carefully at the screenshot, you will see a clock icon, which shows where/when the time of the event is. Using this information, I can then open my calendar and find the event and edit it to suit.

This is too much effort - I would rather simply open the event directly from the email.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your issue is on Outlook web app, right? If so, i'm afraid that you can only access and view meeting details through the calendar.

Instead, when you open the meeting invitation email in Outlook desktop client, there's an option "Calendar" on the top to directly access to calendar.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.